# Como puedo filtrar Json con clave y valor ? Si la clave y valor estan en diferentes niveles

Tags: php, laravel, array, json, jsonarray

Hola amigos tengo un problema al filtrar datos de este Json con PHP, tengo este pequeño arreglo

```
<?php
// Your code here!
$array = json_decode( '[{"cdr":"1373872527187015-901","AcctId":"1","accountcode":"","src":"901","dst":"023827390","disposition":"ANSWERED","amaflags":"DOCUMENTATION"},{"cdr":"1373872585997436-901","AcctId":"2","accountcode":"","src":"901","dst":"023827390","dcontext":"outbound-route-4","clid":"\"901\" <901>","channel":"PJSIP\/trunk_4-00000002","dstchannel":"PJSIP\/trunk_3-00000003","lastapp":"Dial","lastdata":"PJSIP\/023827390@trunk_3,,b(callee-handler^s^1)","start":"2013-07-15 02:16:26","answer":"2013-07-15 02:16:28","end":"2013-07-15 02:16:43","duration":"17","billsec":"15","disposition":"ANSWERED"},{"cdr":"137465454327998-1992","main_cdr":{"AcctId":"","accountcode":"","src":"1992","dst":"023827390","dcontext":"","clid":"","channel":"","dstchannel":"","lastapp":"","lastdata":"","start":"2013-07-24 03:29:03","answer":"","end":"","duration":"72","billsec":"72","disposition":"","amaflags":"","uniqueid":"","userfield":"","channel_ext":"","dstchannel_ext":"","service":"","caller_name":"","recordfiles":"","dstanswer":"","chanext":"","dstchanext":"","session":"137465454327998-1992","action_owner":"","action_type":"DIAL","src_trunk_name":"","dst_trunk_name":""},"sub_cdr_1":{"AcctId":"13","accountcode":"","src":"1992","dst":"023827390","dcontext":"ext-did-4","clid":"\"\" <1992>","channel":"PJSIP\/trunk_4-00000005","dstchannel":"","lastapp":"ForkCDR","lastdata":"ae","start":"2013-07-24 03:29:03","answer":"2013-07-24 03:29:03","end":"2013-07-24 03:29:03","duration":"0","billsec":"0","disposition":"NO ANSWER","amaflags":"DOCUMENTATION","uniqueid":"1374654543.13","userfield":"Inbound","channel_ext":"trunk_4","dstchannel_ext":"023827390","service":"s","caller_name":"","recordfiles":"","dstanswer":"","chanext":"","dstchanext":"","session":"137465454327998-1992","action_owner":"1992","action_type":"DIAL","src_trunk_name":"PBX_251_CISCO","dst_trunk_name":""},"sub_cdr_2":{"AcctId":"14","accountcode":"","src":"1992","dst":"7000","dcontext":"ivr-1","clid":"\"\" <1992>","channel":"PJSIP\/trunk_4-00000005","dstchannel":"","lastapp":"ForkCDR","lastdata":"are","start":"2013-07-24 03:29:03","answer":"2013-07-24 03:29:03","end":"2013-07-24 03:30:15","duration":"72","billsec":"72","disposition":"ANSWERED","amaflags":"DOCUMENTATION","uniqueid":"1374654543.13","userfield":"Inbound","channel_ext":"trunk_4","dstchannel_ext":"7000","service":"s","caller_name":"","recordfiles":"","dstanswer":"7000","chanext":"","dstchanext":"","session":"137465454327998-1992","action_owner":"1992","action_type":"IVR[7000]","src_trunk_name":"PBX_251_CISCO","dst_trunk_name":""},"sub_cdr_3":{"AcctId":"15","accountcode":"","src":"1992","dst":"023827390","dcontext":"ext-did-4","clid":"\"\" <1992>","channel":"PJSIP\/trunk_4-00000005","dstchannel":"","lastapp":"ForkCDR","lastdata":"ae","start":"2013-07-24 03:30:15","answer":"2013-07-24 03:30:15","end":"2013-07-24 03:30:15","duration":"0","billsec":"0","disposition":"ANSWERED","amaflags":"DOCUMENTATION","uniqueid":"1374654543.13","userfield":"Inbound","channel_ext":"trunk_4","dstchannel_ext":"023827390","service":"s","caller_name":"","recordfiles":"","dstanswer":"023827390","chanext":"","dstchanext":"","session":"137465454327998-1992","action_owner":"1992","action_type":"IVR[7000]","src_trunk_name":"PBX_251_CISCO","dst_trunk_name":""}}]' );
$filtrado = array_filter($array, function($val) { return $val["disposition"] == 'ANSWERED' && $val['src_trunk_name'] == 'PBX_251_CISCO' && $val['dst_trunk_name']== 'PBX_ALDEBERAN_CLARO'; });


?>
```

***No logro filtrar los datos de este Json* Ayuda!**

Comment: Un pequeño error de editor

Comment: La estructura de ese json es muy confusa y dudo que lo consigas con lo que has puesto. Para empezar el json_decode genera un array de objetos, por lo tanto las llamadas a $val como si fueran array no funcionan. Luego el valor "PBX_ALDEBERAN_CLARO" no aparece en ese json, por lo tanto tampoco sacarias nada, y despues, esos campos que pretendes sacar estan diseminados entre objetos y subobjetos de forma un poco anarquica y debes estudiar bien esa estructura antes de usar el array_filter tal como la pretendes usar, o mirar de hacerlo recursivo, pero sabiendo donde buscar.

Answer (score -1):

lo conseguí haciendo una validación dentro de funtion() {}, de la siguiente manera

```
$filtrado = array_filter($array, function($val) { 
  if (isset($val["disposition"])) {
    return $val["disposition"] == 'ANSWERED' && $val['src_trunk_name'] == 'PBX_251_CISCO' && $val['dst_trunk_name']== 'PBX_ALDEBERAN_CLARO'; 
  }
});
```

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas conseguido, pero esta respuesta no es correcta al 100% porque no dices que es `$cdrList`.  Usando esta respuesta con la variable **$array** (en lugar de **$cdrList**) de tu pregunta, a mi me da un error así: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`.  Por favor, aclara tu respuesta indicando que es **$cdrList** y como has hecho las conversiones para llegar a ello, y donde esta el valor `PBX_ALDEBERAN_CLARO` que no salia en tu pregunta, y entonces sí que será una buena respuesta.

Comment: Claro amigo, solo es enviar el arreglo, nada mas

Comment: Pues no lo entiendo, tanto en mi PC como en este depurador de código: https://onlinegdb.com/_zzVecGUeO  me da el mismo error que he mencionado antes. ¿Te importaria probar tu código allí y ver si te funciona?  Y si es así, ¿encontrar las diferencias para poderlas poner bien en la respuesta?  Gracias